# Multiple "themes" with SASS Modules

Tags: sass, sass-modules

### Project description

So I have a project that has two distinct brands within a single application. I have a base set of Styles for the components, and then I have two different entry point Scss files as such:

Brand 1

```
brand1-index.scss
 - @import brand1-settings-vars.scss
 - @import base-styles-index.scss
 - @import brand1-specific-styles.scss
```

Brand 2

```
brand2-index.scss
 - @import brand2-settings-vars.scss
 - @import base-styles-index.scss
 - @import brand2-specific-styles.scss
```

Base Styles

```
base-styles-index.scss
 - @import lots-of-small-scss-files.scss
 - @import ... etc.
```

So as you might guess, since it was a pattern in older sass systems, the colors, fonts, and other vars for each brand are named the same, and are then used within the base styles. There are a total of 15 variables.

### What I'm looking for

I'm trying to update this to use the newer module based system, and I don't see any easy way to update this. I want to avoid having to write `with` statements for every single one of my `lots-of-small-scss-files.scss` cause that'll be a nightmare, since I'd have to have each var declared in each file with `!default` to be able to pass them down.

**What I would love** is if there was a way to create a variables file in my base that is then overloaded by my brand vars, and then I just `@use` that file within my base, but I am not seeing a way to do that.

I must not be googling the right thing, cause I'm sure someone has needed to do this, but I can't find anything about it.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I described after "What I would love" turns out to be perfectly possibly. You don't need to explicitly assign the variables tho, just use `@forward` instead of `@use` on the base style's settings file.

### Base Files

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Brand Index File

[image]